# Is it possible to highlight incorrect type references in docstring in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

PyCharm type hinting is great. We use it widely in our projects. But time to time type names in method docstrings get misspelled and some bugs that could have been warned about by PyCharm at development time are missed.

Is it possible to make PyCharm warn me about incorrect type reference in parameter type in docstring? For example if I make a typo like `:type num: lomg` instead of `:type num: long` I want `lomg` to be highlighted as a warning.

Comment: Doesn't spell check already do this?

Comment: Spellcheck would not work if it's a reference to our own class with weird name. It's also easy to confuse names like `ISomeInterface` and `SomeInterface`, while both are spelled correctly. Fully qualified references to classes would be broken after moving class to other package but still fine from spellchecker's point of view.

Comment: You are correct. For such an example or more complicated examples you would need pycharm's type inference/validation check within the doc strings.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is helpful for you, but i was unable to add it as a comment due to my reputation points

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-docstrings-to-specify-types.html

additionally, when a class is misspelled or variable, etc etc, i believe it is highlighted?[image]

what version of pycharm are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2016.1. Sure, PyCharm highlights misspelled variables and classes, but only in code, not in docstrings. Unfortunately types mentioned in docstrings are not validated.

Comment: maybe you can check on their community directly https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm

and share the answer with all of us once they have replied =)   i use pycharm a lot and find this of interest

Comment: Good idea. Here is the link to follow: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207418215-Is-it-possible-to-highlight-incorrect-type-references-in-docstring-in-PyCharm-